# how to resize an image inside a button

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a button in which text description comes at bottom and an image at the top.I saw buttons can do the trick by android:drawableTop attribute but I am unable to resize the image

Methods like adjustViewBounds, android:scaleType="fitCenter", fitXY are not working.

Here is my xml code for the button

```
<Button
            android:text="Start Running"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/run"
            android:onClick = "RUN"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/runner"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0sp"
            />
```

Please suggest something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create horizontal LinearLayout with 2 views there - View with your image set as background and TextView with the corresponding text. After that set OnClickListener for this LinearLayout and process it like a regular button.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
    android:id="@+id/half_overlay"
    android:drawable="@drawable/myDrawable"
    android:width="40dp"
    android:height="40dp"
    />

</layer-list>

Comment: Write this code and apply in button Drawable property

Comment: in drawable directory create a new xml file and past above code. then add in button to write this code     android:drawableLeft="@drawable/drawableimagename"

Comment: First I created a new xml file named draw and pasted your code in it.-> Then I used it inside buttons code by writing android:drawableTop="@drawable/draw". But the app stops after it. Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/half_overlay"
        android:drawable="@drawable/mycreation"
        android:width="70dp"
        android:height="50dp"
        />

</layer-list>